# Laravel Query Builder - >= all(select ...)

Tags: mysql, laravel, query-builder

im trying to get the following SQL into Laravel Query Builder:

```
select * from t_1 where Datum like '2015-08-06 %' and Datum >= all(select Datum from t_1 where Datum like '2015-08-06 %');
```

I dont have any idea how to do that with Laravel Query Builder.

Anyone have some tips for me?

Regards, MasseElch

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$data = DB::table('t1') -> select('Datum') -> where('Datum','>=','2015-08-06') -> get();
```